# the method seems disappear in the extend es6 class when it has the same name with field of the parent class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i wrote the following simple code

```
class Animal {
  speak = 1;
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  speak() {
    console.log(`${this.name} barks.`);
  }
}

const dog = new Dog("test");
console.log(dog.speak);
console.log(dog.speak());
```

the console output as follows

```
1

TypeError: dog.speak is not a function
```

i seems the speak method disappeared.

why this happen.

how can i call the speak method of the subclass Dog

Comment: You cannot have a method and a field with the same name. There's only one property, it can't be both a function and a number. Rename one of them.

Comment: @Bergi if there's only one property, the method should overide the parent class's field, why the overide did not happen.

Comment: No, the method property is inherited from the prototype, while the field property is created on the instance itself.

Comment: @Bergi i think you are right, thank you; by the way, "There's only one property, it can't be both a function and a number", is there any specification to prove this;

Comment: Sure, you can read the [ECMAScript specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/), or trust me on this :-)